# WCF Server - asynchronous method

Tags: wcf

Im new in WCF.
I have WCF service with method

```
public string DoSomething(int i);
```

I call this method from one client and next client can`t get results from this method until the first client finishes method.
How to make this calls asynchronous?

My WCF Service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService
```

My config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint contract="IMyService" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
                <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!--true-->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: How do you host the service and what behaviors your service have? You provided absolutely no information describing your service.

Comment: i run this service from VS in debug mode - maybe this is the reason that one client blocks another, and in normal situation it want appear?

Comment: What type of hosting application are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make asynchronous calls to your service:

In Visual Studio Solution Explorer navigate to your Service Reference in the the project that contains your client application.  Right click your Service reference and choose "Configure Service Reference", then check the box "Generate Asynchronous Operations", then click OK.

It shouldn't be necessary though because you can configure your service to handle multiple requests.  You may want to look at how you have configured InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode.  The basicHttpBinding doesn't support sessions so your service is probably defaulting to InstanceContextMode.PerCall.  For more details see [Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx)

Maybe you have something limiting the number of calls.  For more details see [ServiceThrottlingBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522194.aspx)